# Oracle DB relationship between table and view(materialized view)

Tags: java, mysql, oracle

**How to create reference between table and view?** I have view which consist of two tables created via UNION (ids of this tables are unique cause of same sequencer).
I try to create primary key on view and make reference but its not working for me? Is it even possible to make it like that or with materialized view. Its legacy project with really big data model and a lot of views.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use keys in views. That means

- you can't set a primary key in the view
- you can't reference a view in a foreign key

Answer (score 1):

According to oracle docs. you can create PK (disabled, nonvalidated) on views but this PK cannot be referenced by a FK because it's not validated

> Oracle Database does not enforce view constraints. However, you can enforce constraints on views through constraints on base tables.
>
> You can specify only unique, primary key, and foreign key constraints
>   on views, and they are supported only in DISABLE NOVALIDATE mode. You
>   cannot define view constraints on attributes of an object column.

from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52163

Comment: Yes primary key is in DISABLE state, but is there any possibility to create reference from table to materialized view cause my collegue told me that it is possible.

Comment: @Milkmaid: If the PK is not validated you cannot make an FK reference to that PK because constraints should be valid